# Display posts of one wordpress site on another wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to access and display posts/categories/tags of my one wordpress site to another wordpress site. So how can I do this? Can some one tell me this?

Comment: This dark magic is called "RSS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use RSS feed
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds
You can parse RSS as an XML file using PHP
A RSS reader http://apptools.com/phptools/xml/rss.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have set up wordpress multisite 
then you can do it by using switch_to_blog() function.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use data scraper plugin, through this you can display data of one page/post on another wordpress site all based on div id

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scraper/